# What is the valid name of the contact?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, smartcontracts, truffle

I'm trying to give a name to my smart contract. But All given names is invalid. Where is the mistake? Because I guess all names are alpha-numeric. Can you help me for this?

```
PS D:\Dapp\project\project> truffle create contract Proje1.sol
The name Proje1.sol is invalid. Please enter a valid name using alpha-numeric characters.
Truffle v5.5.6 (core: 5.5.6)
Node v16.14.2
PS D:\Dapp\project\project> truffle create contract proje1.sol
The name proje1.sol is invalid. Please enter a valid name using alpha-numeric characters.
Truffle v5.5.6 (core: 5.5.6)
Node v16.14.2
PS D:\Dapp\project\project> truffle create contract fir1st.sol
The name fir1st.sol is invalid. Please enter a valid name using alpha-numeric characters.
Truffle v5.5.6 (core: 5.5.6)
Node v16.14.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the misunderstood. I don't need write ".sol" files name.

`truffle create contract Proje` is enough.